# SSH freezes after couple of lines printing

Tags: linux, ssh, ssh-agent, ubuntu-20.04, freeze

I am having this weird issue with a server whenever I try to open htop over ssh it hangs, ls works but ls -l hangs after couple of line if I execute history it hangs after printing 50+ line. But mosh seems to working fine. I cant figure out whats the issue here. The server os is ubuntu 20.04

Comment: This could be due to an issue with jumbo frames or the MTU somewhere along the path. Follow the ping tests at https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/737c1z/friendly_reminder_if_ssh_sometimes_hangs/ to see if that helps.

Comment: seems like same issue, is there a solution for this @StefanLasiewski

Comment: If the issue is MTU, the solution is to configure the correct MTU, on the interfaces between the two machines involved (including any router between them).

Comment: To confirm this problem, try the following ping test: https://blah.cloud/hardware/test-jumbo-frames-working/